# Function is looping

Tags: node.js, firebase, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

this firebase function for some reason keeps looping. 
Can someone tell me why Thanks!

//When a user is created, register them with Stripe

```
exports = module.exports = functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}').onUpdate(event => {
    const val = event.data.data();
    if (val === null) return null;
    const email = val.email_address; 
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(`${event.params.userId}`).get().then(snapshot => {
    return snapshot.data();
  }).then(customer => {
        console.log('CUSTOMER EMAIL', customer.email_address);
    return stripe.customers.create({
        email: email,
       }).then((customer) => {
         var data = {
             customer_id: customer.id
        };
          return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(`${event.params.userId}`).set(data, {merge: true});
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is lines

`exports = module.exports = functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}').onUpdate(event => {`

and

`return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('${event.params.userId}').set(data, {merge: true});`

The first one, is asking to be triggered every time there is an update in a users document, and the second one is updating entry in users document.

Aka in simple words, you are modifying users collection entry in a listener that listens for updates in users collection.

You can fix it by changing the first line to be

`exports = module.exports = functions.firestore.document('/users/{userId}').onCreate(event => {`